# Reliably broadcasting the same data to multiple sockets in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking, pthreads

I'm receiving a large amount of data over a TCP socket which I'm looking to send to a number of additional sockets (essentially echoing the contents of the first socket). My requirements are as follows:

- Any data received over the read socket must be sent reliably (in order of arrival) to the write sockets
- Writes must *not* block reads from the primary socket under any circumstances
- Disconnections/broken pipes should never interrupt reading from the inbound socket

Currently I'm using a multi-threaded system that maintains a linked list of data read from the inbound socket, and have threads for each outbound socket. When messages arrive via the inbound socket I signal the outbound socket threads to create a copy of the linked list from the main thread and broadcast the data without interrupting operations. My linked list structure maintains an `fd_set` of file descriptors on the main thread, which it uses to determine when a message has been successfully copied and broadcast by each outbound socket (thus removing it from the list).

This is obviously a lot of moving parts, and I wanted to see if I was missing something fundamental that could be used in a situation such as this.

Comment: You could use a ring buffer instead of a linked list, and multiplexing with select instead of multithreading, but those are the only obvious things I see.

Comment: Why would you have the writers copy the linked list?

Comment: @EOF Because the linked list is constantly being altered/culled by the main thread. I obtain a mutex lock, copy the list and then broadcast the copied list after releasing the lock to avoid blocking reads on the main thread.

Comment: 'fundamental' well, how about flow control?  What will you do if data is being read faster than one of the outgoing sockets can consume it?  If you keep buffering, your memory requirement will runaway.

Comment: Also, as @EOF comments, I don't see any reason for a deep copy of data that is not mutated, (if, indeed, that is what you are doing).

Comment: if your inbound link list is constantly changing then use signals to notify all the outbound thread to monitor the signal and upon reception of that signal, lock the critical section of inbound thread for receiving the data using `mutex` and copy the data received to all the outbound threads and then unlock..This is important because copying a linklist is not `atomic`

Comment: You should really replace this list with the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is similar to what I've been doing for the past two decades.

Don't lock and copy the entire list. Instead, have each sending thread read-lock just the element it's currently sending. Have the receiving thread write-lock each new element and perform element deletion. Allow for a long list to accommodate transient bursts.

You can make the list persistent by memory-mapping it to a file.

Good luck. The task is non-trivial.